# Cassandra Drop Keyspace Snapshot Cleaning

Tags: cassandra

Was reading in Cassandra Documentation that:

> Cassandra takes a snapshot of the keyspace before dropping it. In Cassandra 2.0.4 and earlier, the user was responsible for removing the snapshot manually.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/drop_keyspace_r.html

This would imply that in versions after Cassandra 2.0.4, this is done automatically. If so, what configuration parameter (if any) sets the time before snapshot is automatically removed when doing a DROP KEYSPACE?

For example, in the case of DROP TABLE, gc_grace_seconds is

> the number of seconds after data is marked with a tombstone (deletion marker) before it is eligible for garbage-collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this reference is not accurate, Cassandra does not automatically clean up snapshots for you.

> Cassandra won’t clean up the snapshots for you

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/configuration/cassandra_config_file.html#snapshot-before-compaction

You can remove snapshots using the [nodetool clearsnapshot](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/nodetool/clearsnapshot.html) command, or manually delete the directories & files yourself (this is safe as snapshots are just file [hard-links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link)).

Note also that `gc_grace_seconds` is not related to snapshots, it is used during compactions only.

Comment: if you look at the datastax documentation linked, their comment for that version I was using was "Apache Cassandra™ takes a snapshot of the keyspace before dropping it. In Cassandra 2.0.4 and earlier, the user was responsible for removing the snapshot manually." At that time when I had asked the question, the DATASTAX documentation was ambiguous, hence the question; now it is indeed updated, thus I marked the answer as the right one.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsBackupDeleteSnapshot.html

good point also on the gc_grace_seconds